# Проблема cвязи между двумя энтити

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Имею две энтити: *Train* и *Seat*. У них есть реляция one-to-many:

UML
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Train.java:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "train")
    public class Train {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        // Проблема с реляцией!!!
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "train", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Seat> seats;

        @OneToOne
        private State state;

        @Column(name = "carriages")
        private Integer carriages;

        // Getters & Setters...
}
```

Seat.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seat")
public class Seat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "carriage")
    private Integer carriage;

    @Column(name = "seat")
    private Integer seat;

    // Реляция с поездом
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "train_id", nullable = false)
    private Train train;

    // Getters & Setters...
}
```

Как можно заметить, связка тут *bi-directional*:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "train", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Seat> seats;
```

И

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "train_id", nullable = false)
    private Train train;
```

Собственно говоря, у меня произошла ошибка в бизнес-логике на уровне сервиса, когда я вытаскиваю из расписания JPA Train. Причём, проблемы начинаются лишь тогда, когда я вытаскиваю из поезда список сидений (Seat). В моём Spring MVC приложении вылетает такая ошибка:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.slandshow.models.Train.seats, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Затем, когда я понял первоисточник проблемы, решил дебажить в мейне эти два энтити.

С помощью *SessionFactory* я решил вытащить из БД поезд под конкретным айдишником записи и посмотреть:

```
session.beginTransaction();

Train train = session.get(Train.class, 5l); // Вытаскиваю поезд из базы
System.out.println(train); // Причина ошибки вылезает в переопределённом методе toString

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Так как у меня *toString* переопределён, то я хватаю вот такой стек-трейс:

```
ERROR   2018-09-21 19:42:44,671 [main] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  - Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RattlerStation
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:396)
    at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:1032)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:303)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Train.toString(Train.java:74)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.slandshow.models.Seat.toString(Seat.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

Когда я просто вывожу другие поля Train'а - то всё ок, проблему `Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RattlerStation` вызывает именно `train.getSeats();`

Вот мой Hibernate конфи, просто вдруг дело в нём

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan({"com.slandshow"})
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
    public class HibernateConfig {
        private static final String MODEL_PACKAGE = "com.slandshow.models";
        private static final String JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME_PROPERTY = "jdbc.driverClassName";
        private static final String JDBC_URL_PROPERTY = "jdbc.url";
        private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT_PROPERTY = "hibernate.dialect";
        private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY = "hibernate.show_sql";
        private static final String HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL_PROPERTY = "hibernate.format_sql";


        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            Properties property = new Properties();
            property.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(property);
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME_PROPERTY));
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(JDBC_URL_PROPERTY));
            dataSource.setUsername("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("12345");
            return dataSource;
        }

        private Properties hibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_PROPERTY, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_PROPERTY));
            properties.put(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY));
            properties.put(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL_PROPERTY, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL_PROPERTY));
            return properties;
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
            HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
            return txManager;
        }

    }
```

Что же я сделал не так?

Comment: Каким образом вы создание фактор сессий и открывание сессию?

Comment: @RomanC конкретно с проверкой в мейне я открываю сессию так: https://pastebin.com/a6aZFkYk. И имею такой конфиг: https://pastebin.com/U6ewgheT. А конфиг хибера в Spring-mvc я добавил в вопрос

Comment: А где вы закрывание сессию? И почему у вас маленький пул соединений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toString() плохо переопределен и зацикливается переходя по ссылкам.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

поможет, если нужно вызывать getSeats() когда сессия уже не доступна

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело. Вот цитата из вопроса: "Когда я просто вывожу другие поля Train'а - то всё ок, проблему Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RattlerStation вызывает именно train.getSeats();"

Comment: session.beginTransaction();  
Train train = session.get(Train.class, 5l); // Вытаскиваю поезд из базы  
Set<Seat> seats = train.getSeats();  
session.getTransaction().commit();  
//работает?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pQw4xd66

Comment: Вы были правы, дело в toString